# Local Storage to load cookie

Tags: session, cookies, storage, local

Is there anyway I can use local storage to load a cookie so a user won't have to login
? Someone please help, I'm lost and confused on the capabilities of local storage. Say i have a cookie named lol_SessionID, how do I load that into a webpage with local storage?!

Comment: What language(s) are you using?

Comment: javascript or php it doesn't matter. I just need to load it so I can continue the session. I have to do it for work, everyone uses the same account and my app ,which is a simple html type application that loads iframes, is hosted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP to load the value from a cookie is `$cookie = $_COOKIE['cookieName'];` but I think I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: do you know how I can use localstorage or javascript?  The question is how can I load a cookie so I don't have to login, basically I want to use the cookie or better yet localstorage to maintain the session so a login is not needed

Comment: Sorry, I really don't think I get what you're doing. If you want to store the info in a cookie to avoid a login then go ahead and store a user ID in a cookie. Bear in mind that this is easily hacked, but I don't know if that's an issue for you.

Comment: That isn't too much of an issue, if I store a userid in the cookie will it validate pass the loging everytime?

Comment: I don't code the login session, I simply use login sessions so this is strictly on the client side